# How to mutate few columns depending on certain conditions in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame 'df' as below,

```
R0 <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F')
R1 <- c(15515.88,5156.04,65656,1566.1,11,56)
R2 <- c(515,5156.11,415,1455,47,335)
R3 <- c(123.14,9875,1247,778.04,1445,6645)
R4 <- c(115.88,56.04,6556,166,545,998)
R5 <- c('XX-XX',"AA-AA","VV-VV","YY-YY", 'XX-XX Component', 'YY-YY Component')
df <- data.frame(R0,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5)
```

Where I need to multiply R1 to R4 by '-1' if R5's first 5 char are 'XX-XX' or 'YY-YY'.
I did the below coding which works fine too,

```
library(operators) 
d1 <- df2[stringr::str_extract(df2$R5, "^.{5}") %in% c("XX-XX", "YY-YY"),]
d2 <- df2[stringr::str_extract(df2$R5, "^.{5}") %!in% c("XX-XX", "YY-YY"),]

d1[,2:5] <- d1[,2:5]*(-1)
dff <- rbind(d1,d2)
```

The output is as expected in 'dff', but is there a simple way rather splitting data frames into two and then rbind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, you can use:

```
df[2:5] <- df[2:5] * c(1, -1)[grepl('^(XX-XX|YY-YY)', df$R5) + 1]
df
#  R0        R1       R2       R3      R4              R5
#1  A -15515.88  -515.00  -123.14 -115.88           XX-XX
#2  B   5156.04  5156.11  9875.00   56.04           AA-AA
#3  C  65656.00   415.00  1247.00 6556.00           VV-VV
#4  D  -1566.10 -1455.00  -778.04 -166.00           YY-YY
#5  E    -11.00   -47.00 -1445.00 -545.00 XX-XX Component
#6  F    -56.00  -335.00 -6645.00 -998.00 YY-YY Component
```

We multiply by -1 if `R5` starts with `XX-XX` or `YY-YY`.

Answer (score 4):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(across(R1:R4, ~ if_else(substr(R5, 1, 5) %in% c("XX-XX", "YY-YY"), . * -1, .)))

  R0        R1       R2       R3      R4              R5
1  A -15515.88  -515.00  -123.14 -115.88           XX-XX
2  B   5156.04  5156.11  9875.00   56.04           AA-AA
3  C  65656.00   415.00  1247.00 6556.00           VV-VV
4  D  -1566.10 -1455.00  -778.04 -166.00           YY-YY
5  E    -11.00   -47.00 -1445.00 -545.00 XX-XX Component
6  F    -56.00  -335.00 -6645.00 -998.00 YY-YY Component
```

Comment: I am getting an error, Error: Evaluation error: could not find function "across". Can you suggest?

Comment: Did not help, Is it due to the version? I use Version 1.1.383

Comment: It should be included from `dplyr` version 1.0.0.